# Apache Ignite 2.6 infinity loop connect client to server TcpCommunicationSpi

Tags: java, ignite

When i start client node and connect to server i get infinity loop of messages in server log

```
|[2018.08.21 17:01:22.997]|INFO |r-tcp-comm-1-#26|TcpCommunicationSpi           | Accepted incoming communication connection [locAddr=/10.144.193.157:48100, rmtAddr=/10.144.13.223:46208]
|[2018.08.21 17:01:22.999]|INFO |r-tcp-comm-1-#26|TcpCommunicationSpi           | Received incoming connection from remote node while connecting to this node, rejecting [locNode=ce9b6147-671b-4351-a142-d251a1362920, locNodeOrder=1, rmtNode=866f0d34-8d0c-48a7-809a-a89aeaf0e7f4, rmtNodeOrder=3]
```

My client config

```
        IgniteConfiguration igniteConfiguration = new IgniteConfiguration();
        igniteConfiguration.setClientMode(true);
        igniteConfiguration.setPeerClassLoadingEnabled(true);

        TcpCommunicationSpi cspi = new TcpCommunicationSpi();
        cspi.setSocketWriteTimeout(60000);

        TcpDiscoverySpi dspi = new TcpDiscoverySpi();
        TcpDiscoveryVmIpFinder ipFinder = new TcpDiscoveryVmIpFinder();
        ipFinder.setAddresses(Collections.singletonList(igniteHost + ":" + ignitePorts));
        dspi.setIpFinder(ipFinder);

        igniteConfiguration.setDiscoverySpi(dspi);
        igniteConfiguration.setCommunicationSpi(cspi);
```

My server config

```
<property name="discoverySpi">
            <bean class="org.apache.ignite.spi.discovery.tcp.TcpDiscoverySpi">
                <property name="localPort" value="48500"/>
                <property name="ipFinder">
                    <bean class="org.apache.ignite.spi.discovery.tcp.ipfinder.vm.TcpDiscoveryVmIpFinder">
                        <property name="addresses">
                            <list>
                                <value>127.0.0.1:48500</value>
                            </list>
                        </property>
                    </bean>
                </property>
            </bean>
        </property>

        <property name="communicationSpi">
            <bean class="org.apache.ignite.spi.communication.tcp.TcpCommunicationSpi">
                <property name="localPort" value="48100"/>
            </bean>
        </property>
```

Some times (after fast close and start client app) client connected to server without problems. I fined in **TcpConnectSpi** if block  **if (oldFut instanceof ConnectFuture && locNode.order() < rmtNode.order())** that reverse connection. In **TcpConnectionSpi** i saw that i will connect only when oldFut is null, oldFut can be null when this is first connection to server, but in another block early was init oldFut linked object.
How can i create stable connection client to server?

P.S. i use spring boot 2.0.3 with ignite 2.6.0. Ignite bean starts with Ignition.start(cfg).

Answer (score 0):

These messages usually suggest that you have problems with network topology. Make sure that both clients can connect to server ports and that servers can connect to client ports.

Comment: Hello. On 2.3 version this config work fine and we downgrade ignite version. thx for answer

Comment: There are chances that you will see this problem again, since there are no known regressions after 2.3 in Communication area.

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

**IgniteServer:**

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Date;

import org.apache.ignite.Ignite;
import org.apache.ignite.IgniteCache;
import org.apache.ignite.Ignition;
import org.apache.ignite.cache.CacheAtomicityMode;
import org.apache.ignite.cache.CacheMode;
import org.apache.ignite.cache.CacheWriteSynchronizationMode;
import org.apache.ignite.cache.query.annotations.QuerySqlField;
import org.apache.ignite.configuration.CacheConfiguration;
import org.apache.ignite.configuration.IgniteConfiguration;
import org.apache.ignite.spi.discovery.tcp.TcpDiscoverySpi;
import org.apache.ignite.spi.discovery.tcp.ipfinder.vm.TcpDiscoveryVmIpFinder;

public class IgniteServer {

  private static final String CACHE_NAME = "EmployeeCache";

  public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
    try (Ignite ignite = Ignition.start(igniteInstanceConfiguration())) {
      final IgniteCache<Long, Employee> cache = ignite.getOrCreateCache(igniteCacheConfiguration());

      final Employee employee = new Employee(101L, "OhTeri", new Address("100 Zipline", "Irvine", "CA", 92604),
          new Date(2015, 05, 22));

      cache.put(employee.empId, employee);

      while (true) {
        Thread.currentThread().sleep(300000);
        System.out.println("I will run till you don't kill me....");
      }
    }
  }

  private static IgniteConfiguration igniteInstanceConfiguration() {
    IgniteConfiguration cfg = new IgniteConfiguration();
    TcpDiscoverySpi discovery = new TcpDiscoverySpi();
    TcpDiscoveryVmIpFinder finder = new TcpDiscoveryVmIpFinder();
    finder.setAddresses(Arrays.asList("127.0.0.1:47500..47509"));
    discovery.setIpFinder(finder);
    cfg.setDiscoverySpi(discovery);
    cfg.setPeerClassLoadingEnabled(true);
    return cfg;
  }

  private static CacheConfiguration<Long, Employee> igniteCacheConfiguration() {
    final CacheConfiguration<Long, Employee> cacheCfg = new CacheConfiguration<>(CACHE_NAME);
    cacheCfg.setCacheMode(CacheMode.REPLICATED);
    cacheCfg.setIndexedTypes(Long.class, Employee.class);
    cacheCfg.setAtomicityMode(CacheAtomicityMode.ATOMIC);
    cacheCfg.setWriteSynchronizationMode(CacheWriteSynchronizationMode.FULL_SYNC);
    return cacheCfg;
  }

  private static class Address {
    private final String street;
    private final String city;
    private final String state;
    private final int zip;

    public Address(String street, String city, String state, int zip) {
      this.street = street;
      this.city = city;
      this.state = state;
      this.zip = zip;
    }

    public String getStreet() {
      return street;
    }

    public String getCity() {
      return city;
    }

    public String getState() {
      return state;
    }

    public int getZip() {
      return zip;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
      return "Address{" + "street='" + street + '\'' + ", city='" + city + '\'' + ", state='" + state + '\'' + ", zip="
          + zip + '}';
    }
  }

  public static class Employee {
    @QuerySqlField
    private Long empId;

    @QuerySqlField
    private String name;

    @QuerySqlField
    private Address addr;

    @QuerySqlField(index = true)
    private Date date;

    public Employee() {
      // No-op.
    }

    public Employee(Long empId, String name, Address addr, Date date) {
      this.empId = empId;
      this.name = name;
      this.addr = addr;
      this.date = date;
    }

    public String name() {
      return name;
    }

    public Address address() {
      return addr;
    }

    public Date date() {
      return date;
    }

    public Long getEmpId() {
      return empId;
    }

    public void setEmpId(Long empId) {
      this.empId = empId;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
      return "Employee{" + "empId=" + empId + ", name='" + name + '\'' + ", addr='" + addr + '\'' + ", date=" + date
          + '}';
    }
  }
}
```

> IgniteClient:

```
import org.apache.ignite.Ignite;
import org.apache.ignite.IgniteCache;
import org.apache.ignite.Ignition;
import org.apache.ignite.configuration.IgniteConfiguration;
import org.apache.ignite.spi.communication.tcp.TcpCommunicationSpi;
import org.apache.ignite.spi.discovery.tcp.TcpDiscoverySpi;
import org.apache.ignite.spi.discovery.tcp.ipfinder.vm.TcpDiscoveryVmIpFinder;

import java.util.Arrays;

public class IgniteClient {

  public static void main(String[] args) {

    final IgniteConfiguration igniteCfg = new IgniteConfiguration();
    igniteCfg.setClientMode(true);
    igniteCfg.setPeerClassLoadingEnabled(true);

    final TcpCommunicationSpi spi = new TcpCommunicationSpi();
    spi.setSocketWriteTimeout(60000);
    final TcpDiscoverySpi discoverySpi = new TcpDiscoverySpi();
    final TcpDiscoveryVmIpFinder finder = new TcpDiscoveryVmIpFinder();
    finder.setAddresses(Arrays.asList("127.0.0.1:47500..47509"));
    discoverySpi.setIpFinder(finder);

    igniteCfg.setDiscoverySpi(discoverySpi);
    igniteCfg.setCommunicationSpi(spi);

    Ignite ignite = Ignition.start(igniteCfg);

    final IgniteCache<Long, IgniteServer.Employee> cache = ignite.cache("EmployeeCache");
    final IgniteServer.Employee employee = cache.get(101L);
    System.out.println("Employee From Server Cache:" + employee);
  }
}
```

Comment: Hello. I don`t find important diffirence in our configuration. On 2.3 version this config work fine and we downgrade ignite version. thx for answer.

Answer (score 0):

We test our configuration with 2.6.0 and 2.3.0 version. On 2.3.0 this config work fine. After analize repo we find some commits to TcpCommunicationSpi class that change some in methods that do communication connection. We stay on 2.3.0 version as more stable release.